# Drupal 6: Listing taxonomy vocabularies with tagged nodes underneath

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I want to create a page which list the Taxonomy vocabularies and then list the nodes(created/owned by himself only) with that vocabularies.

example out put:

**Article**

- Article 1 (Title,Body,CCK field 1,CCK field 2)
- Article 2 (Title,Body,CCK field 1,CCK field 2)
- Article 3 (Title,Body,CCK field 1,CCK field 2)

**Podcast**

- Podcast 1 (Title,Body,CCK field 3)
- Podcast 2 (Title,Body,CCK field 3)
- Podcast 3 (Title,Body,CCK field 3)

Here the fields associated with nodes may differ per vocabulary. for example vocabulary Article'll display nodes with four fields (Title,Body,CCK field 1,CCK field 2) and 
Podcast'll display nodes with three fields (Title,Body,CCK field 3) etc.

Using views how can I achieve this? Or any other better approach.

I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177875/drupal-6-views-listing-taxonomy-terms-with-tagged-nodes-underneath) also but not actually fulfilling my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to create Article and Podcast as two separate content types, since they have different field requirements. You could then create two different views for each content type and display them together using a views attachment display.

**EDIT:**

To get views for a specific logged in user, I found some good information here: http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-arguments. Specifically note this code:

```
global $user;
return $argument[0] == $user->uid;
```

I believe you will need to use the above code as a views argument to filter results on a per user basis.

Comment: Thanks bkildow, its working. Could you please guide me how can I display the nodes created by that logged in user only in this View-Attachment? Currently it shows all the nodes of content types.